# methods sequence by NSMutableArray/NSMutableDictionary contents (Image multi-effecting)

Tags: objective-c, image, macos, effects, core-image

### What I want to do:

I want to implement ability for user to use CIFilters on image. So I need somehow to fix it's sequence. For example if user opens image, then applies `CIGaussianBlur`, and then `CIColorControls` and then `CISepia`, I need to get result like that:

```
On user opened image apply CIGaussianBlur -> on CIGaussianBlur output image apply CIColorControls - > on CIColorControls output image apply CISepia.
```

Thats OK. But what if then user turns off CIGaussianBlur? I need then to repeat this effect's sequence just without blur. It would look like this:

```
On user opened image apply CIColorControls -> on CIColorControls output image apply CISepia.
```

### The question

Is it possible to do something like this:

After applying any effect, add some string in NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary. Then when applying another effect, check NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary contents like that:

if object at index 0 is equal to "blur", apply blur on source image, then take blur's output image like current effect's input image

And so on? So that effects would be re-applied every time in their sequence made by user.

If it is possible maybe someone could suggest me any solution?

Comment: Should effects be able to be applied more than once? If so, then NSMutableArray is the obvious choice.

Comment: Wel they can be able to be applied only once, but user always has ability to adjust it's parameters any time. If user does like that:
`CIColorControls->CIGaussianBlur->CISepia->CISaturation` he could get grayscale image, and if he does like that: 
`CIColorControls->CIGaussianBlur->CISaturation->CISepia` maybe he could get sepia tone image? That depends on logic witch will be used when coding it. But thats not a big deal. Both variants are suitable for me.

Comment: And if I choose NSMutableArray, is there any way to check it contents and depending on that add methods sequence, than writing much `if's` in `while` cycle?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is a great instance for the [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28software_concept%29) idea to be used.

You should store your array of filters to process the image as an array - that maintains sort order, and is fairly straightforward to deal with (other than something like a `NSCountedSet`).

The next logical question to ask, then, is how do we apply the factory pattern here? The most important thing to consider is what type should the context object be? Here are a few thoughts:

1. **Using `NSString` as a constant identifier.**

   - Probably the simplest to start, its , and easy to understand - the downside is that it's slower than other options, and can get to be quite the complex `if-else` block, as you cannot use a `switch` statement on a `NSString`.
2. **`NSNumber`, wrapping an enum value.**

   - This is probably one of the better options. You can convert right down to an `int` variable, which compares quite fast on almost any processor I can imagine, and, if you use ObjC 2.5's fancy literals, you could do something like this:

     ```
     [filters addObject:@(filterType_gaussianBlur)];
     ```

     Where `filterType_gaussianBlur` is an enum constant or something.

     Another advantage to using an `enum` is the support for `switch` statements out of the box. It cleans up your code if done properly, it's faster than a large `if-else` block, the only thing to look out for is ensuring that you `break` properly!
3. **Storing `Class` objects**

   - This one may require some explaining. In objective-c, you can actually store a reference to the type of an object, `CIGaussianBlur`, `NSString`, `NSData`, etc.

     This class "object" allows you to dynamically create an object based just on it's type, for example:

     ```
     Class cls = nil;

     if (stringMutable)
         cls = [NSMutableString class];
     else
         cls = [NSString class];

     NSString *mutableOrNot = [[cls alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World!"];
     ```

     However, the disadvantage to this approach would be the inability to configure the objects after they are initialized, and you must use the same selector (method) to initialize each one. If that is not an issue (I do not use CoreImage), then using the `Class` approach should be fine.

All in all, use whatever makes sense in the situation. If these filters need no additional configuration after they have been initialized, then approach **3** makes a lot of sense. I personally wouldn't recommend approach **1**, unless it really is necessary to use a string.   **Whenever you can, always try to control the values that an object can have.** It makes your life much easier, trust me.